# Set struct method as callback

Tags: callback, rust, closures

I have some struct and want a method of this struct to be a callback. I tried to set the callback as a closure and call the method in it, but this does not work.

Here is example of what I want. In this example I use the [Cursive](https://github.com/gyscos/Cursive/) library:

```
extern crate cursive;

use cursive::Cursive;
use cursive::views::{BoxView, SelectView, IdView};
use cursive::view::Selector;


struct SomeStruct {
    siv: Cursive,
}

impl SomeStruct {
    fn new(siv: Cursive) -> SomeStruct {
        let mut ss = SomeStruct {
            siv: siv
        };
        let mut select: SelectView<i32> = SelectView::new();
        select.set_on_submit(|siv, value| ss.on_submit_callback(siv, value));
        ss.siv.add_fullscreen_layer(BoxView::with_full_screen(IdView::new("select", select)));
        ss
    }

    fn on_submit_callback(&mut self, siv: &mut Cursive, value: &i32) {
        println!("value - {}", value);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let siv = Cursive::new();
    let mut ss = SomeStruct::new(siv);
}
```

There are compiler errors:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `ss`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:20:34
   |
20 |             select.set_on_submit(|siv, value| ss.on_submit_callback(siv, value));
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- `ss` is borrowed here
   |                                  |
   |                                  may outlive borrowed value `ss`
   |
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `ss` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword, as shown:
   |             select.set_on_submit(move |siv, value| ss.on_submit_callback(siv, value));

error[E0387]: cannot borrow data mutably in a captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
  --> src/main.rs:20:47
   |
20 |             select.set_on_submit(|siv, value| ss.on_submit_callback(siv, value));
   |                                               ^^
   |
help: consider changing this closure to take self by mutable reference
  --> src/main.rs:20:34
   |
20 |             select.set_on_submit(|siv, value| ss.on_submit_callback(siv, value));
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: Have you read the [book chapter on Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html)? It seems to me you are coming from a higher-level language background where every object is passed around by reference; this is not the case in Rust.

Comment: What is the point of this callback being a method of your struct? You can move it out of the `impl` and use it as a standalone function. Otherwise you will have to `move` values into the closure, because the compiler has to be sure that no dangling pointer will ever show up at runtime.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I came from python.

Comment: And I read the chapter. I mostly ask question not about "what compiler says", "what is this errors means", that I understand. I ask about "how to do it in Rust".

Comment: My point is that I want to pass additional data in callback, not only siv and value. May be there is another solution?

Answer (score 5):

Rust is not very callback-friendly, to be honest.

Callbacks are easy in garbage-collected languages, as sharing an object is an issue, but tend to be more difficult in languages where ownership is explicit. In this case, you have two possibilities:

- event managers,
- plowing on with shared ownership.

The latter is easy enough for small applications, but can become really messy (and leaky) at a larger scale. Still, let's start by it.

---

The most direct translation of Python would be to use shared ownership: a reference counted pointer `Rc`, wrapping some `Cell` or `RefCell` (to defer borrow-checking to run-time).

```
fn new(siv: Cursive) -> Rc<RefCell<SomeStruct>> {
    let mut ss = Rc::new(RefCell::new(SomeStruct {
        siv: siv
    }));

    let mut select: SelectView<i32> =
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(SelectView::new()));

    {
        let weak = ss.clone().downgrade();
        select.borrow_mut().set_on_submit(|siv, value|
            weak.upgrade()
                .map(|ss| ss.borrow_mut().on_submit_callback(siv, value))
        );
    }

    ss.borrow_mut().siv.add_fullscreen_layer(
        BoxView::with_full_screen(IdView::new("select", select))
    );

    ss
}
```

So, let's get our ownership story straight:

- `ss` owns (partly) `select`,
- `select` has a weak reference to `ss`.

The weak reference is necessary to break the cycle, as this would leak.

This solution should work, but as mentioned:

- it's a bit clunky syntax-wise,
- it's a bit complicated to keep track of where to use `Weak` to break the cycles,
- if you try borrowing twice from `RefCell` at the same time, one borrow being mutable, you'll get a `panic`.

In short: it works, but it's not *nice*.

---

The other solution is to use a event manager instead.

Event loops are an easy solution to decouple ownership: instead of directly calling `on_submit_callback` in the callback, push an event to the event manager!

The solution is a bit more involved:

- you need something to own `SomeStruct` (and probably other),
- an ID system (you pass an ID instead of a pointer),
- an event manager that can retrieve a component by ID to dispatch an event to it,
- ...

On the other hand, it works pretty well and a decoupled system can be easier to interact with.

Comment: But to push event to the event manager I need to access to that manager in the callback, that I pass to set_on_submit. Is that right? If so - will I encounter the same problem?

Comment: @sinitsynsv: Indeed, you need access to the manager, or a queue to it (like a [MPSC queue](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/)). Still, this simplifies things somewhat is that before you had a full graph of interdependent objects, now you only have the manager owning the objects, and the objects referencing (weakly) the manager. So instead of a potential full NxN interactions, you only have 2xN. When N increases, this helps a lot.